# Django "Yellow Page" errors not showing up in Chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome

I have Django v 1.6 stable and Python 2.7.5 64-bit.  When I have an error occur in one of my views, a blank page is displayed in Chrome and the following traceback printed in my console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in proce
ss_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finis
h_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\django-1.6-py2.7.egg\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __ini
t__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\SocketServer.py", line 710, in finis
h
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
```

However, when I use IE, the yellow error page displays as intended.

Comment: Does the error happens all the time or just occasionally with each refresh?

Comment: The problem is not related to django. It is common to get this error occasionally, but if it happens all the time, then I would advise you to reinstall chrome and try running the site again.

Comment: To be clear, I only get this on django yellow pages.  If the page can render correctly, it does and no error is shown in the console.

Comment: There's to little information. I've replicated your environment and I don't get any errors. Maybe try updating python to latest (2.7.6)